# NGINX - Short domain proxy to full path on another domain

Tags: nginx

I have two domains, let's say `ex.io` and `example.com`. I own both and have access to both servers. Both run NGINX.

**Goal**: I'd like to have any request from `ex.io` forward to a specific path under `example.com`, e.g. `http://ex.io` passes to `https://example.com/foo/bar`. This has to be done without a redirect (more in **Context**)

**Context**: The goal is to host a shell script at `https://example.com/foo/bar` so that `curl ex.io | sh` will run the shell script. I'd like no redirects to happen so no additional flags are needed for `curl`.

My current `.conf` setup for both servers follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com
    return       308  https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name ex.io;
    return      308 https://example.com/foo/bar;
}
# ...
```

This works, but requires the extra flag `-L` to run properly under `curl`. How can I proxy `ex.io` to go **directly** to `https://example.io/foo/bar`?

*EDIT*: I'm forwarding `http://ex.io/` to `https://example.com/foo/bar` which may be tricky going from `http` to `https`. [Bananenkönig's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64496349/6637709) fails with a `502 Bad Gateway` error and the following logs:

```
2020/10/26 23:28:45 [error] 223#223: *281 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: ex.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443/foo/bar/", host: "ex.io"
2020/10/26 23:28:45 [warn] 223#223: *281 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: ex.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443/foo/bar/", host: "ex.io"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name ex.io;
    location /some/location/on/ex.io/ {
        proxy_pass https://example.com/some/location/on/example.com/;
    }
}
```

when you want ex.io/ (on location /) to be forwarded to example.com/... write "location / { "

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this out, and it sadly didn't seem to do the trick. I've added an edit at the end with the logs from your solution.